# Spring cloud functional style and integration-test

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream

I have a Spring Boot 3.1.6 project using Spring Cloud 2022.04 and Spring Cloud Stream 4.0.4.

It is setup so the integration-test consumes events produced by the application to verify them.

Like so:

application.yml:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    function:
      definition: input
    stream:
      bindings:
        input-in-0:
          group: input-consumer
          destination: input_topic
```

application-integration-test.yml:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    function:
      definition: integrationTestInput
    stream:
      bindings:
        integrationTestInput-in-0:
          group: test-consumer
          destination: output_topic
```

Such a setup works fine before rewriting it to the functional style.

When the test run the 'input-consumer' is not registered to the 'input_topic'.

I have verified this using offset explorer Kafka tool.

I works if I change it like so - put function name from main application.yml into test yml:

application-integration-test.yml:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    function:
      definition: input;integrationTestInput
    stream:
      bindings:
        integrationTestInput-in-0:
          group: test-consumer
          destination: output_topic
```

My question is, why is that needed?

I fear this is related to the fact that I also cannot get Kafka consumers setup when it is imported from another module that has its own @Configuration that sets up consumers. I.e. bindings from both a dependency and from main application. It works fine with @StreamListener.

Comment: Please create a simple project that reproduces the issue. You've included a lot of information but no test itself and only partial project configuration . We have been with functional model for the past 4 years and configuration above does work, so something else must be missing. So sample project in Guthub somewhere will help for us to diagnose and help you resolve your issue

Comment: It must be something in our rather complex setup then. I feared as much. I'll try and boil it down to see where it goes wrong. Thanks